# angular v6 and amazon-cognito-identity-js

Tags: angular, amazon-cognito

Below is my is my app.component and error.  How do I resolve that error?

```
index.js:43 Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined
at Object../node_modules/buffer/index.js (index.js:43)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:76)
at Object../node_modules/amazon-cognito-identity-js/es/AuthenticationHelper.js (vendor.js:69868)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:76)
at Object../node_modules/amazon-cognito-identity-js/es/index.js (vendor.js:74053)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:76)
at Object../src/app/app.component.ts (main.js:96)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:76)
at Object../src/app/app.module.ts (app


import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Router,ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
//import * as AWSCognito from 'amazon-cognito-identity-js';
import {AuthenticationDetails, CognitoUser, CognitoUserAttribute, CognitoUserPool} from 'amazon-cognito-identity-js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit,OnDestroy {
  title = 'app';

  PoolData = {
    UserPoolId: environment['pool_id'],
    ClientId: environment['pool_app_client_id']  
  };
  userPool:any;

  constructor(public router: Router,
              private route: ActivatedRoute){

                this.userPool = new CognitoUserPool(this.PoolData);
              }

  ngOnInit(){

    console.log(this.router.url)
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      console.log(params)

  });

  }

  ngOnDestroy(){

  }
}
```

Comment: for the dude that this hit and run with the dec.....hey provide a comment wy you did so

Comment: This post fixed my issue: https://github.com/aws/aws-amplify/issues/678

Answer (score 4):

It simply means that the global variable which is used by node is not defined. Global in node is equivalent to window in javascript.

There are few ways you can solve this issue:

Add this to your index.html header:

```
<script>
  if (global === undefined) {
    var global = window;
  }
</script>
```

Or add to polyfill.ts:
(window as any).global = window;

I assume a simple google search would give you the answer.